# Why is the Vuetify autocomplete not showing the data in the component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a form inside a Vue component using Vue.js & Vuetify but the list of schools I want to display in the autocomplete box are missing. I have included them as an array in the data function in the component but they are not showing up and the following error is thrown in the console.

[Vuetify] Unable to locate target [data-app]

```html
    <template>
     <div class="app">
      <v-card width="500">
       <v-card-title class="pb-0">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
       </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-form>
          <v-text-field
            required
            label="Email"
            type="email"
            prepend-icon="mdi-email"
          />
          <v-text-field
            required
            :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
            label="Password"
            prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
            :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
            @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
          />
          <v-text-field
            required
            label="First Name"
            prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
          />
          <v-text-field
            required
            label="Last Name"
            prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
          />
          <v-text-field
            required
            label="Preferred Username"
            prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
            placeholder="This name will be seen by others and identify you on the site"
          />
          <v-autocomplete
            label="Which school do you attend?"
            :items="schools"
          ></v-autocomplete>
        </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn color="info">Sign Up</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
     </v-card>
    </div>
  </template>
   <script>
     export default {
       name: "signup",
       data: function() {
         return {
           showPassword: false,
           schools: [
           "Ipswich High School",
           "Northgate High School",
           "Kesgrave",
           "Ipswich Academy"
           ]
          };
         }
       };
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Vuetify to work, you need to wrap all of your content into a `<v-app>` component. The error tells you that you're missing this component.

```html
    <template>
      <div class="app">
        <v-app>
          <v-card width="500">
            <v-card-title class="pb-0">
              <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-form>
                <v-text-field
                  required
                  label="Email"
                  type="email"
                  prepend-icon="mdi-email"
                />
                <v-text-field
                  required
                  :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
                  label="Password"
                  prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
                  :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                  @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
                />
                <v-text-field
                  required
                  label="First Name"
                  prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
                />
                <v-text-field
                  required
                  label="Last Name"
                  prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
                />
                <v-text-field
                  required
                  label="Preferred Username"
                  prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
                  placeholder="This name will be seen by others and identify you on the site"
                />
                <v-autocomplete
                  label="Which school do you attend?"
                  :items="schools"
                ></v-autocomplete>
              </v-form>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn color="info">Sign Up</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-app>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of the component will not work properly unless the form is contained within a `<v-app></v-app>` wrapper